# Understanding ref-qualified member-functions

Tags: c++, reference

Is the ref-quilifier for only overloading sakes? I expected that

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    A() : a(10){ }
    void foo() &{ a++; std::cout << this -> a << std::endl; }
};

int main ()
{
    A a;
    a.foo();
    std::cout << a.a << std::endl;
}
```

and

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    A() : a(10){ }
    void foo(){ a++; std::cout << this -> a << std::endl; }
};

int main ()
{
    A a;
    a.foo();
    std::cout << a.a << std::endl;
}
```

Prints different result because in the first case we passed implicit object parameter by reference and in the second case, in turn, we passed it by value.

Comment: That's not what it does. It's for distinguishing between member calls on a named object vs. a temporary one.

Comment: @chris So, for the overloading.

Comment: Really can't get it why you expected different results.

Comment: @St.Antario, Not necessarily. It might make sense to provide only one. For example, calling `begin` on an object that is about to be destroyed is almost always wrong.

Comment: The implicit object parameter is always passed by reference. Otherwise member functions would not be able to update member variables...

Comment: @chris Didn;t understand what you meant. What's the begin? The begin method of an stl-container returning the iterator pointing to the first elemnt?

Comment: @MattMcNabb So, couldn't you get an example where we should really use the ref-quiliefer. I meant something that's not artificial.

Comment: @St.Antario, Yes, that was my example. You'll occasionally find code doing `foo(getContainer().begin(), getContainer().end());`, where `getContainer` returns by value, and then the iterators mismatch. It would be kind of nice to have that be caught by the compiler.

Comment: @St.Antario Yeah, using it on `operator=` is a good place. Then the compiler will reject `foo() = x;` where `foo()` returns by value.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Scott Meyrse in his Effective C++ proposed to return const from the `operator=` to prevent such an assignment. I guess it was before introducing ref-qualifiers with member-functions, wasn't it?

Comment: I never really liked that idea... personal preference I guess.